# getting "//" after the URL

Tags: ubuntu, web, nginx

I'm running nginx web server. I have not written any rule to redirect abc.com to www.abc.com, I have just added both in server_name directive which looks like,

server_name abc.com www.abc.com;

My doubt is, when I hit the URL in browser, like abc.com it redirect to www.abc.com//. What does this "//" means ? Do I need to change anything in my nginx conf file ?

Comment: Does `abc.com` have the proper DNS record? Some (most?) browsers will try www.abc.com if the user enters abc.com and that doesn't resolve.

Comment: Yeah! abc.com has proper DNS set.